# Windows Store Apps, download multiple files with threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I have this following method that I use to download a file's content:

```
public async Task<String> DownloadFileService(String filePath, string id)
{
    string resposta = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = Constants.baseAddress })
        {
            string token = App.Current.Resources["token"] as string;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            string fname = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
            path = path.Replace(fname, "");
            StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.DataDirectory + "\\" + path, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            StorageFile imgFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fname, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (var response2 = await httpClient.GetAsync("file?fileId=" + id))
            {

                Stream imageStream = await response2.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[imageStream.Length];

                imageStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);


                await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(imgFile, bytes);
                resposta = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }

        }
        return resposta;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I would like to know how I can call this multiple times to download several files at same time and wait until all files are downloaded, then do other stuff.

**EDIT**

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753700/windows-store-apps-download-multiple-files-with-threads/30753758#30753758) suggestion I tried creating the following method:

```
public async void checkFilesExist(JsonArray array, string path)
{
    List<Document> list = new List<Document>();
    ObjectsService obj = new ObjectsService();
    List<Task> ts = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        JsonObject newDoc;
        JsonObject.TryParse(item.Stringify(), out newDoc);

        if (newDoc.ContainsKey("libraryType") || !newDoc.ContainsKey("fileName"))
            continue;
        string name = newDoc["fileName"].GetString();
        string id = newDoc["_id"].GetString();
        File file = new File(name);
        file.id = id;
        Document doc = file;
        doc.Parent = Document.FromPath(path);

        path = path.Replace("/", "\\");
        StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.DataDirectory + "\\" + path, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        try
        {
            await folder.GetFileAsync(file.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            list.Add(doc);
            Task x = obj.DownloadFileService(doc.GetFullPath(), file.id);
            ts.Add(x);
            Debug.WriteLine(" Ex: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(ts.ToArray());
        Debug.WriteLine("AFTER THrEADS");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Ex2:  " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

What this does is, with a response in json I get from a webservice listing some files, I check if they already exist in localfolder.
If they don't I call the method I had at start of the question.

I then have a list of tasks, and I add the call of the `DownloadFileService()` as a new task in the list, after that I do the `Task.WaitAll()` to wait for the downloads to finish.

Using fiddler I see the downloads all start, but for some reason my code doesn't stop at `Task.WaitAll()`, it just keeps going and it starts to use the files that are still being downloaded, creating a bunch of problems :D

Comment: have you try debugging your code? put a break point on line `Task.WaitAll(ts.ToArray());` and see if the code reaches there or not.

Comment: with some break points, the behaviour i see is something like, it reaches the await folder.GetFileAsync(file.Name); then it does the code after the checkFilesExist method call, after that it goes to the code in the catch after the folder.GetFileAsync(file.Name);

Comment: ok , so i changed Task.WaitAll to await Task.WhenAll and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx). It waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

```
var t1 = DownloadFileService("file1", "1");
var t2 = DownloadFileService("file2", "2");
var t3 = DownloadFileService("file3", "3");

Tasks.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use :

```
await  DownloadFileService("Path", "id");
await  DownloadFileService("Path", "id");
await  DownloadFileService("Path", "id");
await  DownloadFileService("Path", "id");
```

Comment: how it waits for all of them to be completed?

Comment: since `public async Task<String> DownloadFileService(String filePath, string id)` represents a task there is no problem, but if asked me how the framework does it, i can't answer that sorry

Comment: assume you want to write "done" after all these tasks finished. how would you do that?

Comment: Need to remove the await from each assignment and assign each Task to a variable then use `Tasks.WaitAll(var1, var2, var3, var4);`

Otherwise, the code above will just run sequentially.